# What to do if adding an insignificant interaction term severely increases p value of main effect?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, anova, interaction

I'm analysing a dataset consisting of 24 animals, subdivided in 12 pairs of animals which are sampled from 12 representative litters of animals. Both animals in each pair are of the same sex, with a total of 12 animals per sex. One animal in each pair is fed diet 1, and the other is fed diet 2. Of interest is whether there is an influence of diet, and whether there is an interaction between diet and sex

To analyse this, I am using Restricted Maximum Likelihood (lmer routine in R): (y ~ Diet + Sex + Diet:Sex + (1|Pair))

This yields a result I don't know how to deal with; Diet has a t value of -1.55, Sex -3.23, Diet:Sex -0.77. This seems fairly straightforward; sex has a significant effect, yet diet does not. However, removing the interaction term from the model suddenly makes Diet jump up to -3.02. Additionally, running this same model with an ANOVA routine gives an F value of 8.76.

One potentially interesting fact: the correlation of fixed effects between Diet and Diet:Sex is -0.7.

How should I deal with this?

Comment: From your description I see that diet and sex should be independent (not correlated) and dichotomized variables, right?

Comment: Yes this is exactly true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think you could be interested in this [paper](https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol16-1/p033/index.html). Basically, I think it is up to you to decide what model is better.

Complete reference : Lorah, J. A. (2020). Interpretation of main effects in the presence of non-significant interaction effects. *The Quantitative Methods for Psychology*, *16*(1), 33-45. https://doi.org/10.20982/tqmp.16.1.p033

Comment: Thank you, I will read this paper!

Comment: Could you please include a full citation for the paper in case the link dies?